# How to create a simple virtual filesystem on google app engine blobstore using python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, temporary-files

There is a Java version GAEVFS which seems quite effective but also complicated.

And a Python vfs collection at  http://code.google.com/p/pyfilesystem/ which is not designed for GAE.

Google locked its **file system** and make **tempfile** empty, which needs a workaround.

I have to build a simple vfs with [GAE blobstore/file API](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/blobstore/blobstore.py?r=126) to emulate a Linux-style dir-file-owner-permission behavior.

Is it possible? What are the most fundamental **classes, attributes and methods** I should implement?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to implement FS in GAE prepare for a world of pain. You can't write files on GAE, even if you move to [Managed VMs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms/) your disk will be wiped on restart.

You'll basically will have to emulate a file system interface and translate that to datastore entities and relations.

It can be done, but you are gonna have to do it from the ground up.

If you want to have a cloud file system i suggest you consider cloud storage which actually allows you handle files, it actually implements most of the features of a basic file system.